# Chessboard filled with numbers, having same sum always if exactly $1$ number is taken from each row and each column

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

Consider the squares of an $8\times 8$ chessboard filled with the numbers $1$ to $64.$ If we choose $8$ squares with the property that there is exactly one from each row and exactly one from each coloumnwise, and add up the numbers in the chosen squares, show that the sum obtained is always $260.$

Numbers filled the squares as in the figure below.
https://1drv.ms/w/s!AsgThsrHfCMVhns1x3plDZjTFI5O

Comment: Nah question is to show it will be 260 always

Comment: The accepted answer in @RobertZ's link does prove that. Are you asking something you did not understand in that answer?

Comment: +1 to the *style* of OP's reactive comment.  Although I disagree with the underlying math analysis inherent in his reactive comment, I must show appreciation for his syntax.

Comment: @user2661923 Not a good way to handle it. Questions should be formulated out in the body, they should not be dependent on a link. A "good style" whatever this means here, does not compensate that.

Comment: @Peter I'm not sure what you are saying here.  If you are indicating a disagreement with the OP's reaction : I have found that if you attempt to criticize the OP directly, they will often "dig their heels in".  If instead, you go for "light satire" the OP may not be so defensive.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just think of how the number will be chosen

if you fix the row first, see the number you take will be of form {the $8$'th column number $-a$} where $a$=$0,1,2,3....7$

so the sum will be $(8-x_1$)+$(16-x_2$)$+(24-x_3$)+$(32-x_4$)+$(40-x_5$)+$(48-x_6$)+$(56-x_7$)+$(64-x_8$)

now see all $x_i$'s are distinct and take values from {$0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7$}
then the sum is $260$

In fact, if you think for $n×n$ chessboard the answer will be $n(n^2+1)/2$

you can read this article here
https://www.awesomemath.org/wp-pdf-files/math-reflections/mr-2020-05/mr_5_2020_counting_with_aid_of_cyclotomic_polynomials.pdf

Comment: can I ask ,are you solving 10+2?